# Ionic detect "back" for better Native Page Transitions

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement native page transition into my Ionic project after reading great tutorial from http://www.gajotres.net/handling-native-view-animations-with-ionic-framework/.

However, I found the problem that sometimes the page is changed after the page transition is made. Meaning, it will animate transition from page A to page A. Only then, page A become page B. The solution provided by the article and also the plugin is by estimate setting the delay before the animation begin. But this way of doing isn't very reliable.

So, I am thinking instead of using delay, but apply the animation on entering that page with this:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function (event, viewData) {
    window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide({
            "direction": "left"
        });
});
```

It works great when navigate from other page to this page. But it will be animation problem when navigate BACK from other page to this page.

How can I know user is BACK to this page so that I can perform different direction of animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're intercepting the `$ionicView.enter` event, you can check the direction of the animation.  The callback function receives 2 parameters. The second one will give you that information so you could do something like this:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function (event, viewData) {
    var transitionDirection = viewData.direction !== "back" ? "left": "right";
    window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide({
         "direction": transitionDirection
    });
});
```

the second parameter `viewData` has a property `direction` with the direction of the animation: `back` or `forward`.

You can do the same thing when leaving the view:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.leave", function(event, viewData){
    var transitionDirection = viewData.direction !== "back" ? "left": "right";
    window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide({
         "direction": transitionDirection
    });
});
```

There's a bunch of other [events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/) you can use:

- $ionicView.enter
- $ionicView.leave
- $ionicView.beforeEnter
- $ionicView.beforeLeave
- $ionicView.afterEnter
- $ionicView.afterLeave
- $ionicView.loaded
- $ionicView.unloaded

Comment: Your solution is awesome COOL. I was working on my solution to make it works. Your solution is much better!!! Anyway, is there any global '$ionicView.enter' thing so that I can just put it once and it will work on every page?

Comment: I am afraid not. You can use the event `$stateChangeSuccess` in the `$rootScope` but I guess you will have to check which state is going where: `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) { });`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. One thing I don't know. Seems we are animate it on '$ionicView.enter', why is it sometimes I still see the same page being animate in, only then the page is changed? Is there any way to totally avoid it from happen?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand this question. I guess I should have to see how you're doing things.

Comment: You can better seeing the problem by running ionic on low end phone and set the `androiddelay` option for native transition to 0. When I do this, I will see 90% of the time the same page is transition in, only then the page is change. This shouldn't be happen as we are doing it on `$ionicView.enter`. Anyway, if I put the `alert` inside `$ionicView.beforeEnter`, it will work fine. So, I guess most likely is because the ionic event does not called accurately. With `alert` pausing the script and make it accurate. Is there any other thing like `alert` can make it accurate?